# Text box is not being set a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Afternoon all.

I am grabbing information from a webService and then populating a series of Textboxes based on this information.

The information is an array named response formatted like such:

```
FieldName, FieldValue, FieldName, FieldValue, ...
```

Where each `FieldName, FieldValue` is a `result`

When I print the information out using :

```
response.ToList().ForEach(v => v.results.ToList().ForEach(x => str1.Append(String.Format("{0} : {1}", x.fieldname, x.fieldvalue))));
```

I get the following string:

```
... Warehouse : 01 StockType : 5 ...
```

But when I try and assign these values to a textbox using:

```
response.ToList().ForEach(v => v.results.ToList().ForEach(x => (((TextBox)infoHolder.FindControl("txt_" + x.fieldname)).Text) = x.fieldvalue));
```

all of the fields are populated **except** warehouse.

Any ideas or suggestions to as why would be appreciated.

All ASP controls are mocked like:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_NAMEOFRETURNFIELDHERE" class="form-control forminput" Style="overflow: hidden;" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Have you double check the spelling of warehouse in your `TextBox`? Since that's the only one that doesn't work. Check if `FindControl` is actually finding it.

Comment: you would probably misspelling the ID for warehouse control.

Comment: See answers for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of warehouse and make sure that the field ID in your ASPX matches what your code constructed in the run time, Doing a simple debug on that when the field name is "warehouse" will help.

Also did "FindControl" find that control or not?